How to Embed Spring Config Server and Client in the same application?
I am trying to embed the spring config server and client in the same application. According to the spring documentation, I created a composite profile. I am getting the below error when I run the application. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'searchPathCompositeEnvironmentRepository' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'git-env-repo1': https://external-configurations.git: not authorized

Expected:

Fetch git username and password from the vault
Using above credentials connect to external configurations git repo (file name is myConfigServer-dev.yml)
Overwrite the configs in local application.yml file

bootstrap.yml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: composite, dev

  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        composite:
          - type: vault
            backend: secret
            profile-separator: "-"
            application-name: myConfigServer
            default-context: myConfigServer-dev
            order: 1
            vault:
              uri: {vault uri}
              authentication: approle
              app-role:
                role-id: {role-id}
                secret-id: {secret-id}
              kv:
                default-context: myConfigServer-dev
              generic:
                profile-separator: "-"
              kvVersion: 2

          - type: git
            uri: {git repo uri}
            username: ${git.username}
            password: ${git.token}
            default-label: master
            clone-on-start: true
            order: 2
    vault:
      uri: {vault uri}
      authentication: approle
      app-role:
        role-id: {role-id}
        secret-id: {secret-id}
      kv:
        default-context: myConfigServer-dev
      generic:
        profile-separator: "-"
``


why you have to do this, this seem like not a good practice for the config server.

Our purpose is to simplify the deployment
